# Focussed working, is there an app for that?

Tags: software-recommendation

So this isnt like a technical question, just some advice.

This is my issue:
A few years ago I had a medical problem but I'll spare you the details.
One of the results is a lack of concentration and motivation.
How it works is that I can get a burst of enthusiasm and work away at a project for hours on end, then it's like I hit a large wall (literally from one moment to the next, not gradual) where I can't continue and the project gets abandoned.

Now motivation is something you can't really fix with an app.
But,
I have seen that there are apps that allow you to write without distractions, but I do programming (currently HTML, PHP and CSS but also a lot of Python).
Is there an app that either allows me to kinda make previous code typed not seem so daunting, or perhaps an app that can make me focus solely on the task at hand?

I know it's a bit of an odd question, but any ideas are very welcomed, even if it's just advice.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could also, use the pomondoro technique(google it) with the indicator for ubuntu(setting your own time).

Also, if you're working with firefox, installing addon: greasemonkey with script: invisibility cloak is great. You set a time after which you're able to visit time-consuming sites aka facebok, etc. It works for me :)

If the kind of distractions you want to avoid are time-consuming sites, my solution works. 
Additioanally you can use workflowy, which is absolutely great for focusing on a matter at a time! I am a CS student, so I am using it A LOT at my projects.

Comment: I do like this idea!
My problem isnt so much that I take time on other sides or get distracted by them. But I get to the point where I begin lacking motivation to continue and then I do anything in order to avoid carrying on, I'm sure we all suffer from that lol.

Thanks for the ideas, I'll look into them

Comment: Indeed we all suffer from these, that's why I am using these tools :P You should also, work for about 90' or less, and then have a break for 15'. Then again work for the same amount of mins. Thus, when you are working you'll know that you have a 15' break waiting for you. Also, for the motivation part only, using workflowy and dividing what you have to do in small increments is the best. You focus on that bullet(at workflowy) only and when you finish it, you can mark it as "Completed". This all entails, motivation++ ;)

Comment: Yeah this got me thinking, I think that when I do finish this project, to create a small application for just this. One that automatically blocks sites etc for x amount of time and then perhaps open a site by itself when the break comes. Sort of like a reward idea.

Comment: Yeah you could do that. The blocking is covered by the invisibility cloak script for greasemonkey ;)

Comment: Gotta love the Ubuntu community, thanks for all the ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a writing app called FocusWriter which is a very distraction free text editor. It does however not support any syntax highlighting.

It is available for free download in the Ubuntu Software Center.

And here is a link to their webpage:
http://gottcode.org/focuswriter/

Comment: Yeah I seen that, but I was hoping for syntax highlighting, although to be fair, I think that might just be a far stretch. But I think what might be ideal is like with KDE's workspaces. There you are able to set a workspace for work and the apps you require show up and folder views etc, but only them, and personal workspace shows apps you use normally. I was hoping maybe something like that existed. Thank you anyway for your idea!

Comment: Perhaps you can set up Gedit to be just as distraction free? I know it supports Syntax highlighting for _a_lot_ of different languages, and is very customizable.

Comment: You may also want to try Xmonad as a desktop environment.

Comment: @user117123 Good idea--you might consider expanding that into a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the distraction editor.

Having checked out focuswriter, I started looking through Google for similar apps and stumbled upon Marave.
It doesn't work perfectly as I need to start it with sudo in order to save, but it's fullscreen and distraction free, thanks very much for the input